# Flex layout is not honoring width of fixed columns

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems with the bottom div getting wider when adding alot of text to the center div.

**HTML:**

```
<body>

<div class="k-box k-flex k-flex-row black k-flex-item">
    <div class="k-box cyan" style="width: 200px;">
        <div class="k-box" style="height: 100%;">Left which should always be 200px!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="k-box k-flex k-flex-column  k-flex-item">
        <div class="k-panel k-flex k-flex-column  k-flex-item">
            <div class="k-box k-flex-item" style="">When the text is short it works!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="k-box green" style="width: 200px;">right</div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="k-box k-flex k-flex-row k-flex-item" style="">
    <div class="k-box cyan" style="width: 200px;">
        <div class="k-box" style="height: 100%;">Left which should always be 200px!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="k-box k-flex k-flex-column k-flex-item">
        <div class="k-panel k-flex k-flex-column  k-flex-item">
            <div class="k-box k-flex-item">When long... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vehicula ante eget aliquam semper. Vestibulum aliquam rhoncus sem nec tristique. Aenean sagittis turpis tellus, asemper tellus laoreet eu. Suspendisse condimentum auctor sapien eget ullamcorper. In a efficitur neque, vel ullamcorper nulla. Vestibulum sed suscipit neque. Ut in blandit erat. Aliquam sed feugiat nulla, vel porttitor tortor. Curabitur interdum turpis et dolor lobortis, non eleifend diam ornare. In sem nisi, egestas eget nisl ac, lobortis tristique sem.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="k-box green" style="width: 200px;">right</div>
</div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div.k-flex {
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.k-box {
    position: relative;
}

.k-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}

.k-flex-item {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -moz-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.k-flex-row {
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}

.k-flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
```

How can I make the left and right column in the bottom div stay 200px wide and also make the middle automatically start scrolling when content is getting to tall for the div?

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eugfcLo2/1/

Comment: try adding a bounty for this, it requires extensive css testing

Comment: Have you tried setting a `max-width` for the offending divs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the whole point of Flexbox is to be *flexible*, so saying something like *always 200px* is a thing you don’t really want to do with Flexbox. You *can* do it by setting a width/max-width, but the better thing to do is to use [flex-basis](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-basis/). So if you set your flex basis to 200px, those columns will try their best to be 200px. They’ll still flex if the layout requires it (in this case when the window gets too small), but in general they'll stay 200px.

Example:

```
.k-flex {
    display: flex;
    height: 150px;
}
.k-flex-item {
    flex: 1 1 200px; /* flex basis is the third property */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gj21nyh0/

(I also added that height on the parent, to make it easier to see how scrolling would work)

**Update:** as vals pointed out below, the second value is *flex-shrink*, if you set that to 0 then it keeps the main column from shrinking below flex basis. Depending what you need for your layout, could be useful. Thanks vals!

Comment: Well, yes, it is meant to be flexible. But it is flex style to say that you don't want less than flex-basis, that is what flex-shrink is about

Comment: I had figured out that flex is flexible but I want exactly 200px. In the end I got all I needed so I'm more than happy. :)

Comment: @Asken Kudos for getting into it while it's still fairly new! This stuff isn't as easy as it could be. :)

Answer (score 2):

The missing property is `flex-shrink`

if you set it to 0, you are telling the flex system that you don't want your initial size to shrink.

Set it along with the `width: 200px` and it will work.

But the usual way to do it would be to set `flex: 1 0 200px;` this set grow to 1, shrink to 0, and also flex basis to `200px;` more *flex* than setting the width

Answer (score 0):

Set `min-width:200px;` for the left column, as per suggestion comment from Shaggy.

http://jsfiddle.net/eugfcLo2/6/

Any reason why this wouldn't work? I think this solves the issue.